# Print kind of a target in Bazel

Tags: bazel

How do I find out the `kind` of a target?

`bazel query //...` prints the labels of the targets but I'd like to know their kind.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--output label_kind` option.

For example, the following will print the kind of all targets in the workspace:

`bazel query //... --output label_kind`

Other output formats: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#output-formats